Reached maximum depth for account resolution when running test case
When running test case
  it("initialize_candidate", async () => {
    await voting_program.methods
        .initializecandidate("Candidate 1", new anchor.BN(1))
        .rpc();

    await voting_program.methods
        .initializecandidate("Candidate 2", new anchor.BN(1)).
        rpc();
});

the error occurs as
  ● Voting › initialize_candidate

    Reached maximum depth for account resolution


pub fn initializecandidate(ctx:Context<InitializeCandidate>, _poll_id:u64,candidatename:String,)->Result<()>{
        let candidate= &mut ctx.accounts.candidate_account;

        candidate.candidate_name = candidatename;
        candidate.candidate_votes=0;
        Ok(())
    }

pub struct InitializeCandidate<'info>{
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer:Signer<'info>,
    
    pub poll_account:Account<'info,Poll>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        space = 8 + CandidateAccount::INIT_SPACE,
        seeds = [poll_id.to_string().as_bytes(), candidatename.as_ref()],bump,
    )]
    pub candidate_account: Account<'info,CandidateAccount>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info,System>,

}

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct CandidateAccount{
    #[max_len(400)]
    pub candidate_name:String,
    pub candidate_votes:u64,
}


Check that the candidateAccount is less than 32 bytes as this is the limitation that PDA seeds in anchor have to adhere to.
If you are using long strings, you can hash the seed
ref: best ways to store long string as PDA seed
